# Accessing AVCaptureDevice Modes iOS7 successfully?

Tags: iphone, ios7, avfoundation, avcapturedevice

I'd be thankful for any help on this:

For my augmented reality app (Vuforia SDK), I'm trying to lock the iPhone 5 camera's exposure, focus and white balance using the AVFoundation framework. The following builds – but when used, the camera doesn't bother:

```
void LockCam(){

NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

        for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) {
    if ([device lockForConfiguration:nil]) {
        [device setWhiteBalanceMode:AVCaptureWhiteBalanceModeLocked];
        [device setExposureMode:AVCaptureExposureModeLocked];
        [device unlockForConfiguration];}

}}
```

Yes, I have copied all of this together from other posts as I am new to Objective-C. But as this builds and hence doesn't throw any error message I'm kind of lost now …

Can anyone here be my iOS fairy? :)